# MSSQL, get the Largest value in Column A for each Group of Column B

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
id  name   NumofPup     Decade 
---|-----|------------|--------|
1  | Ace | 7          | 1930   | 
2  | Bel | 6          | 1930   | 
3  | Cha | 2          | 1930   | 
4  | Bel | 10         | 1980   | 
5  | Dew | 6          | 1980   | 
6  | Bel | 2          | 1990   |
```

The table shows how many articles a person wrote in a decade. So for example, Bel wrote 6 articles in 1930, 10 on 1980, 2 on 1990.

I need for each decades, get the person who wrote the MOST article. Result should be like this:

```
id  name   NumofPup     Decade 
---|-----|------------|--------|
1  | Ace | 7          | 1930   | 
4  | Bel | 10         | 1980   | 
6  | Bel | 2          | 1990   |
```

Following is the code I have so far that generates Table 1:

```
SELECT authDec.name, COUNT(authDec.name) as NumOfPupPerDECADE, authDec.decade
FROM
    (
    SELECT a.name, year, (year/10)*10 AS decade
    FROM publication pub, author a, authored auth
    WHERE year IS NOT NULL and pub.pubId = auth.pubId and auth.id = a.id
) as authDec
GROUP BY authDec.name, authDec.decade
ORDER BY authDec.decade, NumOfPupPerDECADE DESC
```

Author holds name and AuthorID
Publication holds pubID and ArticleName
Authored holds AUthorID and pubID

And I am stuck. So my question is, how I get Author who wrote most Articles in each decade?

Answer (score 1):

One method of doing this is to use row_number() function:

```
with cte as (
    select *, row_number() over(partition by Decade order by NumofPup desc) as rn
    from Table1
)
select id, name, NumofPup, Decade
from cte
where rn = 1
```

Or like this:

```
select t.id, t.name, t.NumofPup, t.Decade
from Table1 as t
where
    exists (
        select 1
        from Table1 as t2
        where t2.Decade = t.Decade
        having max(t2.NumofPup) = t.NumofPup
    )
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c2f06d/1)</kbd>**

Note that there're might be more than one person who wrote maximum number of articles in decade, so first query will return first person in alphabetical order who wrote maximum, second query will return all persons (see sql fiddle example)

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE (ID INT,  NAME VARCHAR(40),   NUMOFPUP INT,    DECADE INT )
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES

(1  , 'ACE' , 7          , 1930)  , 
(2  , 'BEL' , 6          , 1930)   , 
(3  , 'CHA' , 2          , 1930 )  , 
(4  , 'BEL' , 10         , 1980)   , 
(5  , 'DEW' , 6          , 1980 )  , 
(6  , 'BEL' , 2          , 1990)   

SELECT 
    ID, 
    NAME, 
    NUMOFPUP, 
    DECADE 
FROM 
    @TABLE A 
WHERE 
    A.NUMOFPUP = (SELECT MAX(NUMOFPUP) FROM @TABLE B WHERE A.DECADE = B.DECADE GROUP BY B.DECADE)
ORDER BY 
    A.DECADE ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

There are usually 2 ways of solving these issues that would work in any DBMS:

**Left join approach:**

```
SELECT t1.* FROM t t1
LEFT JOIN t t2 ON t1.Decade = t2.Decade AND t1.NumOfPup < t2.NumOfPup
WHERE t2.Decade IS NULL;
```

**Subquery approach:**

```
SELECT t1.* FROM t t1
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT Decade, max(NumOfPup) maxNumOfPup FROM t
  GROUP BY Decade
) s ON t1.Decade = s.Decade AND t1.NumOfPup = s.maxNumOfPup
```

Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/10408/1).

Both of them will result in:

```
| ID | NAME | NUMOFPUP | DECADE |
|----|------|----------|--------|
|  1 |  Ace |        7 |   1930 |
|  4 |  Bel |       10 |   1980 |
|  6 |  Bel |        2 |   1990 |
```